# Browser not parsing html tags returned by an angular pipe

Tags: html, angular, angular-pipe

What I want to happen is provide a value to a pipe, and let the pipe turn it into a list. This might not be the best way to go about it but it's the first thing that came to mind.

Basically I have a simple table. And I have my template as such

```
<tr *ngFor="let res of results">
    <td>{{res.value1}}</td>
    <td>{{res.value2 | list}}</td>
</tr>
```

My `list` pipe is as such.

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'list'
})
export class ListPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, args?: any): any {
        let newList: string[];
        newList = value.split(',');
        let output = '&lt;ul&gt;';
        newList.forEach(val => {
            output += `&lt;li&gt;${val}&lt;/li&gt;`;
        });
        output += '&lt;/ul&gt;';
        return output;
    }
}
```

My expected result would be something like

```
<tr>
    <td>value 1</td>
    <td>
        <ul><li>value2.a</li><li>value2.b</li></ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But what's happening is the literal values `<ul><li>value2.a</li><li>value2.b</li></ul>` are being rendered in my page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you should use `innerHTML` property to display it:

```
<td [innerHTML]="res.value2 | list"></td>
```

And change your pipe like:

```
let output = '<ul>';
newList.forEach(val => {
  output += `<li>${val}</li>`;
});
output += '</ul>';
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abfn63?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)**

The interpolation `<td>{{res.value2 | list}}</td>` doesn't work because angular creates text node and updates its `nodeValue` property so it will displayed as string.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `*ngFor`? You're already using it on the `tr`

Comment: So the answer above answered my question. But I could have gone that route too. I was just looking for a clean way to do it with as little code as possible.